# JLabel. Proper way to setup text read from a xml file?

Tags: java, xml, swing, jlabel

I'm reading a string from an xml file and stumbled across two problems.
First the string dosen't containt html < br> for line breaking, so the JLabel is just one line.
Second I'd like to make the JLabel fit in height according to the "size" of the text. below I sat the height of the JLabel to 200px, but if e.g there's just one word, the JLabel vertically and horizontally centers the text.

Am I missing some "easier" way to do this?

```
String text = "some long string";

JLabel jltxt = new JLabel(text);
jltxt.setBounds(207, 5, 200, 200);
```

Comment: *"First the string dosen't containt html < br> for line breaking, so the JLabel is just one line"*  That's not a question.  Do you **have** a question, and if so, what is it?  *"Second I'd like.."*  And this is a Q&A site, not a help desk.  Each question thread should deal with one question.  Start another thread for the other one.  And don't forget to *ask a question.*  BTW - Java GUIs ..

Comment: .. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  Hard code some 'XML' (as it might appear in the input file) in a `String` ..

Comment: Equally, you could also us a `JTextArea` set to auto line/word wrap and make it non-editable and non-focusable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setBounds(207, 5, 200, 200);` use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));` and try the code below

```
String text = "some long string";

JLabel jltxt = new JLabel(text);
//jltxt.setBounds(207, 5, 200, 200);
jltxt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
jltxt.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
jltxt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

**Note:**
For line wrap use html tang in your text

Comment: It dissapears entirely when trying that. My JLabel is inside a JPane if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: What is the 'Layout` of the JPanel

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)